# How do I use my domain with my AWS Lightsail container service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cloudflare, cname, amazon-lightsail

I have my own domain (mydomain.com) registered at Namecheap and pointed to CloudFlare name servers.

I have successfully deployed (Nextjs + Nginx) container in AWS Lightsail container service, which has public domain like **myservice.random.us-west-1.cs.amazonlightsail.com**

I have added following CNAME records in CloudFlare DNS:

```
type: CNAME
name: mydomain.com
target: myservice.random.us-west-1.cs.amazonlightsail.com
ttl: Auto
proxy status: Proxied

type: CNAME
name: www.mydomain.com
target: myservice.random.us-west-1.cs.amazonlightsail.com
ttl: Auto
proxy status: Proxied

SSL/TLS encryption mode: Full
```

Even though I can see requests in CloudFlare dashboard, my site shows "**404 No Such Service**"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you override your local DNS to point to the host does it work?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams How do I do that? Lightsail container service gives me only public domain: myservice.random.us-west-1.cs.amazonlightsail.com

Comment: If you ping that quickly to get the IP (this will change over time but should be good enough for this quick test), then update your local machines hostfile to add a line of "ip target_hostname" you can discount CloudFlare from it

Comment: I tried with both `ping` and https://www.uptrends.com/tools/find-ip-address-of-my-website to get IP addresses, I got 3. But all of them return "404 No Such Service".

Comment: When you access just the lightsail domain does that work?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly at (https://)myservice.random.us-west-1.cs.amazonlightsail.com Thing to notice: it enabled and redirects to `https` automatically, I didn't configure.

Comment: Hmm can you confirm whether your're listening for any specific hostnames or whether you're reliant on the default configuration (the catch all hosts)?

Comment: I just want to use my domain name (mydomain.com) with Lightsail container service, and I need CloudFlare's freebies. I want to access my site via mydomain.com

Answer (score -1):

You are missing one step. Add a cname with the subdomain name to your service name example:
cname subdomain.example.com service.ramdom.us-east-1.cs.amazonlightsail.com